# Singular homology using singular cubes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homology

When singular homology is defined using cubes instead of simplices it is important to factor out the degenerate cubes in the course of building the singular chain complex. If you omit this step it is easy to compute that the homology of a point is not right. However, the other axioms: Homotopy, Excision, Long Exact Sequence seem to survive even without factoring out the singular cubes. Perhaps I am wrong and one of these axioms also fails in which case that answers my question: but otherwise, if it is only the dimension axiom that fails then the resulting homology theory should correspond to some particular spectrum: so which homology theory is it?

Comment: The obvious guess would be: Product of Eilenberg - Mac Lane spectra realizing the unreduced cubical homology of a point.

Comment: What is the unreduced cubical homology of a point?

Comment: There is one cube of each dimension $\geq 0$, but all of the boundary maps are trivial, so the unreduced cubical homology of a point is one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in each dimension.